# is that normal the size of trained model is too big (40GB) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, ensemble-learning

I have trained a `Random Forest` classifier and a `RusBoost` classifier on almost 11M records. the size of the trained model is 13GB and 40GB respectively. 
Is this normal to have such a big size of the model? I am wondering if the model has trained correctly or not?

Thanks